# Says "failed to start" while booting, then sometimes starts anyway

Tags: boot

After a fallout with Microsoft I'm back to running Ubuntu on two of my computers. It mostly works fine, but when I start my old laptop (HP Pavilion, about ten years old) the loading sometimes stops while displaying "ubuntu 22.04" with the added message "failed to start". If I just leave it sitting for a while it sometimes starts anyway. A very odd problem, has anyone seen it before and is there anything that can be done about it?